# mysql update command example two tables - SPEED UP

Tags: mysql, inner-join

Say you have 2 tables with email in common between them and you want to set an binary value of 1 to the match field - this query works just fine

...but it is very SLOW and puts a huge load on the server if you're dealing with a large number of records (and we are)

```
UPDATE  table1 a
        INNER JOIN table2 b
            ON a.email = b.email
SET     a.match = 1;
```

Does anyone know of the exact same functionality but written with syntax that would put less load on the server and process the query faster?

Thanks!

Comment: There's no better way. Make sure both tables have `email` indexed.

Comment: If `email` column is not unique, then inner join might return too much rows, lets say table1 has `test@example.com` in 20 rows, and same for table2 then your join would return 400 rows, which could be a reason for the slowness.

Comment: did you try to run `EXPLAIN UPDATE ...` to check what is going on? (if you have version 5.6.3 or above)

Answer (score 0):

Before running the query be sure to index both tables. In our case Table 1 has unique values whereas Table 2 has multiple records with the same email (i.e. different websites)

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX email ON table1 ( email );
    
CREATE INDEX email ON table2 ( email );
```

Once these indexes were created on those two tables, the query runs very fast.